# Extract original text from cell with LEFT formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm using the [LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079?hl=en) function like this:

```
LEFT("Lorem Ipsum", 5)
```

Is it possible to get hold of the original text ("Lorem Ipsum") from a cell in which the formula above is used? If I just reference the cell I get just "Lorem".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of unknowns here as to actual usage. But assuming the `LEFT` formula were in A2, the following formula would work in a number of cases:

`=IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH(FORMULATEXT(A2),CHAR(34)&".+"&CHAR(34)),REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A2),CHAR(34)&"(.+)"&CHAR(34)),INDIRECT(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A2),"\(([^,]+),"))),"???")`

This should extract the original source text, whether it is within quotes in that A2 formula or whether A2 uses a reference to some other cell (e.g., `=LEFT(A1,5)`).

If the above formula can't find anything that makes sense (i.e., if you had some math formula in A2 instead of a text-based formula like `LEFT`), then it will just return `???`.

Comment: very nice work !

Comment: Thanks, @Daniele. Of course, this solution centers on your seed idea below. I just fleshed it out.

Comment: I was trying to do it too but you were much quicker :)

Answer (score 0):

start with:

=FORMULATEXT(A2)

if A2 contains LEFT("Lorem Ipsum", 5)

Comment: I understand how this will return a string: `=LEFT("Lorem Ipsum", 5)`, but there must be more to it than this, yes? How does the OP "get hold of the original text ("Lorem Ipsum")"?

Comment: @Tedinoz
 "start with" is the key! he does not take the original text only with that formula ... but that formula had to be his starting point, as in fact can be seen from the goal reached by
Erik Tyler